# exhaustMap with calling API

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working with this sample [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gh7dav-9pacdp?file=package.json,app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts,app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.scss) in stackblitz

It used exhaustMap to call a getProducts function with return Observable

```
   this.filteredLookups$ = filter$.pipe(
      switchMap(filter => {
        let currentPage = 1;
        return this.nextPage$.pipe(
          startWith(currentPage),
          //Note: Until the backend responds, ignore NextPage requests.
          exhaustMap(_ => this.getProducts(filter, currentPage)),
          tap(() => currentPage++),
      }));
```

In getProducts function, I want to call a http to get data from API.

But it looks like we need to return inside the getUsers function, like this:

```
   // Fake backend api
  private getProducts(startsWith: string, page: number): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`api call filter: ${startsWith}`);

    const take = 10;
    const skip = page > 0 ? (page - 1) * take : 0;

    console.log(`skip: ${skip}, take: ${take}`);

    //call http here
    this.userService.getUsers(skip, take).subscribe((result) => {
      return of(result.data);
    });
  }
```

And I have error: "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."

So, how to get result and pass to exhaustMap?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the call, no subscribe to it !

```
  private getProducts(startsWith: string, page: number): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`api call filter: ${startsWith}`);

    const take = 10;
    const skip = page > 0 ? (page - 1) * take : 0;

    console.log(`skip: ${skip}, take: ${take}`);

    //return call http here
    return this.userService.getUsers(skip, take).pipe(map((result) => {
      return result.data;
    }));
  }
```